# C# ASP.NET Core MVC application with Avro

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I want to replace JSON data transmission in ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC application with byte transmission. I chose `Avro` but it could also be something else.

Here is the code in my controller:

```
byte[] model = AvroConvert.Serialize(person, CodecType.Brotli);

return View(model);
```

The problem is in my `.cshtml` views. My `@model` definition now doesn't match with data:

```
@model PersonDTO
```

Without using JSON, I call view passing a byte array as model. It's possible to change deserialization system before pass data to the view?

Another idea is to create a class that inherits from `RazorPage<T>`:

```
public class CustomRazorPageModel<TModel> : RazorPage<TModel>
```

In this case I should define the method `ExecuteAsync` but I can't find any example. Usually abstract classes are created. I can follow this path too, but then would there be a method to override to modify the deserialization of the response arriving from the server?

Comment: In a MVC app there's no need for data transfers, just because the controller calls the view passing the model directly, as an inprocess call. Thus, it could be not that clear what you understand by *I call view passing a byte array as model* and how JSON fits the picture here. I guess you could edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Hi, I updated my question with two lines of code from controller. Where I say `I call view` I mean the `View` method in controller.

Comment: There's completely no point in serializing the model passed to the view. You don't want that.

Comment: @WiktorZychla There isn't any performance improve?  In this case I can limit myself to serializing only the REST calls with Avro.

Comment: *There isn't any performance improve* Not at all. Model instances between controller and view are passed directly, as method call arguments. Yes, you can limit your custom serializator to REST calls.